# Launch a webpage on a Firefox (win) tab using Python

Tags: python, windows, command-line

I'm trying to launch a website url in a new tab using python in that way, but it didn't worked in these both ways:

Method 1:

```
os.system('C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe -new-tab http://www.google.com/');
```

and Method 2:

```
os.startfile('C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe -new-tab http://www.google.com/');
```

If I don't add the parameters (-new-tab http://www.google.com/) it works, opening the default page.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You need to use the [`webbrowser`](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html) module

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('http://www.google.com')
```

[**edit**]

If you want to open a url in a non-default browser try:

```
webbrowser.get('firefox').open_new_tab('http://www.google.com')
```

Comment: Yes, but what if my default browser is not Firefox?

Comment: If the user's default browser is not Firefox, should you force them to use it?

Comment: Nice tip. Thanks. But still don't open the page in a new tab instead of new window. Thanks.

Comment: @John: I'm trying to provide a .xpi extension from an URL, so I need the user to open it with Firefox (no Flock or any other associated app).

Comment: @Leandro I changed the call to open_new_tab it should open a new tab now

Comment: Interesting... I've never played with the webbrowser module before. I'll have to stash that one off in the back of my brain for future use. Thanks Nadia.

Comment: @Nadia, awesome! Really easy solution!

Comment: Ah, I've noticed that it doesn't work on Windows, get this error: "could not locate runnable browser"

Comment: hmm, here is someone asking about the same issue http://echochamber.me/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=23436 the module itself is supposed to work on windows

Comment: Cool, I've added the firefox to the BROWSER env var, but no luck, I'll check with the PATH. Thx.

Comment: FWIW, I only needed to add the mozilla\firefox installation directory to my PATH -- no other env vars were needed to make `webbrowser` work with firefox and Python 2.7.

Comment: Is it possible to launch firefox having no menubar, no status bar and no toolbar through python?

Comment: @Leandro Ardissone Add `%s` to the end of the path to open it by Firefox. `webbrowser.get('C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe %s')`

Answer (score 12):

If you want to start a program with parameters the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module is a better fit:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call([r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe',
    '-new-tab', 'http://www.google.com/'])
```

Comment: what if firefox was not installed? what if it was installed in a different directory? this is not the right way to do. Even if it works in some cases

Answer (score 3):

Use `os.startfile()` passing only the url.  This will cause the URL to be opened in a new tab/window in the user's default browser, which is much nicer to your user.

Comment: Same issue, I need to open it in Firefox instead of the default browser.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try:

```
import os
os.spawnl(os.P_NOWAIT, r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe',
          r'FireFox', '-new-tab', 'http://www.google.com/')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use Mozilla class in webbrowser:

```
import webbrowser
firefox = webbrowser.Mozilla("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe")
firefox.open('http://www.google.com')
```

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple way of opening URL in python using different packages-
using selenium package-

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = '/Users/abcarp/bin/chromedriver')
browser.get('https://in.linkedin.com/')
sleep(10)
browser.close()
```

download firefox driver and placed at user/username/bon location and change the name to firefox.

using sub-process package-

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen([r"/Volumes/Firefox/Firefox.app", "http://www.google.com"]) 
p.kill()
```

using mechanize package-

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://machinelearningstories.blogspot.com/")
br.close()
```

using web-browser package-

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.get('firefox').open_new_tab('http://www.google.com')
```

closing opened web page-

```
import os
os.system("taskkill /im chrome.exe /f")    #( windows)
os.system("pkill -f Chrome")    # mac
```

same information in some more detail is mentioned here-
http://pythonfordatabuggers.blogspot.com/2020/04/automatically-open-and-do-some-actions.html

Answer (score 0):

opening a link without internet explorer and use firefox, just make sure firefox is the default web browser.

```
import webbrowser


http = 'http://'
links = input()
b = webbrowser.open_new(http + links)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 2.7 on windows 7 machine (my setup), if you use:

```
webbrowser.open('google.com')
```

It will open legacy windows explorer (yeah I know right...).

BUT, if you use:

```
webbrowser.open('http://google.com')
```

It will load the url in you default web browser, in my case Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

os.chdir('C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox')    #address of exe file

os.system('firefox.exe')   # name of exe file
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive with your answer, not just code.

Answer (score 0):

as firefox command help `firefox --help`

```
--new-tab <url>    Open <url> in a new tab.
```

so use `--new-tab` instead of `-new-tab`

Answer (score -2):

the best thing to do is to make FireFox as your defalt browser then you would not have to specify your path