# Spawn a new non-blocking process using Python on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, subprocess, nonblocking

I found some articles and even stack|**overflow** questions addressing this subject, but I still can't do it..

What I want to do is open an instance of firefox from python. then the python application should keep minding its own business and ignore the firefox process.

I was able to achive this goal on Windows-7 and XP using:

```
subprocess.Popen()
```

On OS X I tried:

```
subprocess.Popen(['/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin'])
subprocess.call(['/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin'])
subprocess.call(['/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin'], shell=True)
os.system('/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin')
```

(and probably some others I forgot) to no avail. My python app freezes till I go and close the firefox app.

**What am I missing here? any clues?**

Comment: This previous answer works for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832331/launch-a-webpage-on-a-firefox-win-tab-using-python/832338#832338

Comment: Firefox is just an example in this case (that's why it's not in the title or tags). My process needs to be able to open any other process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to detach the process somehow. I snatched this from [spawning process from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972362/spawning-process-from-python)

```
import os
pid = os.fork()
if 0 == pid:
  os.system('firefox')
  os._exit(0)
else:
  os._exit(0)
```

This spawns a forked headless version of the same script which can then execute whatever you like and quit directly afterwards.

Comment: You could simplify this a lot. Unfortunately, I can't really put it in this comment.

Comment: I thought about going this route and even gave it a short try but couldn't get it to work. You're code make my main process exit..

Comment: @Leeron: When you say "my main process" are you referring to firefox or the python script? The `os._exit` calls quits the process, so if you're referring to your python script and you don't want it to exit immediately afterwards, just remove that one line.


@Robin: Yes, you could, but would it make the sequence easier to understand?

Comment: Well what finely (or at the moment) worked was using fork and calling os.system then os._exit when in the child process (your code without the else block) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To show what I meant:

```
import os
if not os.fork():
    os.system('firefox')
os._exit(0)
```

Version that doesn't quit the main Python process:

```
import os
if not os.fork():
    os.system('firefox')
    os._exit(0)
```